# How do I connect to a Netcool / Omnibus "Object Server" using Python?

Tags: python, database

I'm trying to connect to a Netcool 7.1 Object Server using Python, but I'm running into issues. It seems to be a Sybase type database, but stripped down. I'm using the Sybase module and freetds, but I get the following error when I try to connect:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netcool.py", line 12, in <module>
    db = Sybase.connect('foo','foo','foo','foo')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Sybase.py", line 1194, in connect
    datetime, bulkcopy, locale, inputmap, outputmap)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Sybase.py", line 850, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Sybase.py", line 898, in connect
    status = conn.ct_options(CS_SET, CS_OPT_CHAINXACTS, not self.auto_commit)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Sybase.py", line 272, in _servermsg_cb
    raise DatabaseError(msg)
Sybase.DatabaseError: Msg 17001, Level 10
No SRV_OPTION handler installed.
```

Has anyone successfully connected to a Netcool Object Server using Python? Is there any way I can edit the Sybase module to make it work? Worst case scenario, would it be possible to write something that communicates with the nco_sql client? I want the ability to read and write to the DB.

Any help or info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I figured this out on my own. If you use the SAP Sybase JDBC drivers (jconn4.jar) in conjunction with the JayDeBeApi module, you can successfully connect and read/write to the object server. This is the only Python solution I could find that works. If anyone else has an different method, feel free to share.